# How to implement virtual GT on restcomm ussd

Tags: ussd, restcomm

I make a little lab to learn about USSD, then I discover USSD Restcomm. My architecture is like that:
two USSD gateways are connected to the MSC on SS7, these two gateways have their own real GT. Each gateway have one Restcomm Connect.

All of this system works very well but what I want to do is to load balance the trafic between the MSC and the two gateways by using virtual GT. Is anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature will only be available in our commercial version of the Restcomm USSD Gateway and SS7 Load Balancer targeted to be released in Quarter 1 of 2018. Feel free to reach out to Telestax to know more